# How to see last remote commit comment without doing pull

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to find a way to see the last remote commit comments without doing a pull.

I know I can do a

```
git log -1
```

to see the local commit, but what can I do for the remote commit?

Comment: Would you rather not use `fetch`?

Comment: if I need to use a fetch I will but I dont always want to have the changes of the remove local.. do I always need a fetch

Comment: @JohnathanMarkSmith Doing a fetch is easy and harmless. Do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
git fetch origin
```

to fetch commits from the remote `origin`. Now you can see the commit messages with

```
git log origin/master
```

(Replace `origin/master` with whichever branch you wish to view.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked: there's no stock way at all to show remote commits, you need the actual objects present to inspect them.  To get the remote to run any pre-prepared code you want, best I can do is write a pre-receive exit that hunts for special branch names and runs prepared commands before rejecting the push to any of them.  It's a rather disgusting kludge even as kludges go.

But as the commenters point out, fetched commits are compressed extremely well, there'd have to be some very special reason not to do it the easy way.